# How to test redux-saga take with pattern function by Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, redux-saga

I have some saga using take effect to get action by pattern. Now, I'm trying to test it:

Saga:

```
export function* mySaga(spaceId) {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(
      action =>
        action.type === MEDIA_SESSION_RESPONSE &&
        action.payload.data.category === ScreenShareData &&
        action.payload.data.topicId === spaceId
    );
    const remoteScreenSessionId = action.payload.data.content.sessionId;
    yield put(addRemoteScreenSessionId(remoteScreenSessionId));
  }
}
```

Test:

```
it('test', () => {
        const gen = sagas.mySaga('space_1');
        expect(gen.next().value).toEqual(
            take(
                action =>
                    action.type === MEDIA_SESSION_RESPONSE &&
                    action.payload.data.category === ScreenShareData &&
                    action.payload.data.topicId === spaceId
            )
        );
    });
```

In take pattern I have an anonymous function, so how I can to test that pattern in take is equals to pattern, I provide in test?

Test result now is:

```
Expected value to equal:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "combinator": false, "payload": {"pattern": [Function anonymous]}, "type": "TAKE"}
Received:
  {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "combinator": false, "payload": {"pattern": [Function anonymous]}, "type": "TAKE"}
```

If I will use JSON.stringify, I can't be sure that patterns are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest can help you assert on the order of effects layer. In unit testing, you want to test a snippet of code (i.e saga, function, etc) not a flow of execution chain. Hence, the pattern you are trying to test is given `[Function anonymous]`.

There is a little library called [k-redux-saga-tester](https://github.com/rakunteam/k-redux-saga-tester#k-redux-saga-tester) that can provide you with the flexibility of asserting on patterns. Fill in the `VALUE`s and create the necessary mocks for `MEDIA_SESSION_RESPONSE`, `ScreenShareData`, `spaceId`. It should look something like this:

```
describe('mySaga', () => {
     describe('search', () => {

        const test = tester(mySaga) <--- your saga
        const spaceId = 'VALUE';
        const MEDIA_SESSION_RESPONSE = 'VALUE';
        const ScreenShareData = 'VALUE';
        const payload = { data: { category: VALUE, topicId: VALUE }};
        const action = { type: 'YOUR_ACTION_TYPE', payload: { payload }};

        it('should search and set something', () => {
          const mocks = {
               take: [action =>
                    action.type === MEDIA_SESSION_RESPONSE &&
                    action.payload.data.category === ScreenShareData &&
                    action.payload.data.topicId === spaceId]
          }

      expect(test(mocks)).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
  })
})
```

In general, if you want to test the pattern, use a separate test for testing only that specific function. And assert it output given different arguments.